# Using Cross join in Asp .net Web API getting error

Tags: mysql, asp.net, linq, web-services

Hi i am Using Cross join through in Asp .net Web API with a mysql database and getting the following error :

**Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)**

This is my controller code

```
 private myappEntities db = new myappEntities();
    public IQueryable<comment>GetPicturesandtheirCommnets()
    {
        var combo=from p in db.picturedetails 
                    from c in db.comments

                    select new
                    {
                        p.iduser,p.idpictures,p.likes,p.nuditylevel,p.picTitle,p.pictime,p.fakeslevel,
                        c.comment1,c.ctime,c.idcomments,c.spamlevel,c.targetpictureid

                    };
        return combo;

    }
```

Why am i getting this error?? Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query (combo) returns an anonymous type, and your method signature says you are returning an `IQueryable<comment>`.  You can't return anonymous types from methods, so you have two options:

Option 1: Select just fields from the Comment table to return.

Option 2: Create a new class that includes details from Comments and PictureDetails, and modify your query to select new `CommentAndPictureDetails` (or whatever you name your class).

The modified query would look like this:

```
var combo=from p in db.picturedetails 
                    from c in db.comments

                    select new CommentAndPictureDetails
                    {
                        IdUser = p.iduser,
                        IdPictures = p.idpictures,
                        Likes = p.likes,
                        NudityLevel = p.nuditylevel,
                        PicTitle = p.picTitle,
                        PicTime = p.pictime,
                        FakesLevel = p.fakeslevel,
                        Comment1 c.comment1,
                        CTime = c.ctime,
                        IdComments = c.idcomments,
                        SpamLevel = c.spamlevel,
                        TargetPictureId = c.targetpictureid
                    };
```

Your class declaration for `CommentAndPictureDetails` would be like so:

```
public class CommentAndPictureDetails
{
    public string IdUser {get; set;}
    // I don't know the data types, so you'll have to make sure 
    // the .NET type matches the DB type.
}
```

Comment: I am using database first approach, with two separate columns for comments and picturedetails. So after using Option 2, will  the data from those two tables in my database will be fetched?

Comment: The data will still be fetched.  You're just storing it in a Data Transfer Object (DTO) that facilitates the logical (in the Business Logic sense) composition of the data.

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<myapp.Models.CommentAndPictureDetails>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<myapp.Models.comment>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)